# Implement search form with spring MVC

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I would like to do a page document/search where i have a input field, submit button and cancel button.

After have populate the search field i search on the database and back the result (and show it with a table)

The part where i do the search and back the result is already done but...

How to implement a stop button that "stop" the search and... how is possible to show the results "on demand" when they are find and not all together when the method is finished ?

I'm using spring MVC + Hibernate + JPA

Answer (score 1):

You have to learn two things here.
1)For stoping and even to resume search, do the search operation on seperate thread.
when ever you get hold of stop simply send this signal to thread.

2)For showing results in the middle before entire search completes,if you are using db stuff.
you can limit the search read sql/hibernate .for displaying results page by page this concept is called pagination read about it.

Comment: For pagination is ok but, if i dont want pagination but i want to display result each found? for example i have a table where i show result and for every result the table is "refresh". So at time 0 i have 0 rows, time 1 i have 1 row, time 2 5 rows and so on.